# How to retrieve SCDF apps metadata through Docker Labels with local containerd registry?

Tags: docker-registry, spring-cloud-dataflow, microk8s

I'm working with `SCDF 2.9.1` on `microk8s` in dev mode and I'm not able to see my apps metadata in SCDF dashboard.
A `docker inspect` shows the right labels :
[image: Docker Label snapshot]
The Docker image is pushed to containerd local registry : localhost:32000.
I tried to add the registry in SCDF server Config Map like this :
[image: Config Map snapshot]
But it is still not working. I have errors in SCDF server logs :

> ApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver : Failed to retrieve
> properties for resource Docker Resource
> [docker:localhost:32000/mycomp/myapp:latest] because of
> ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

What am I doing wrong ? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I think the problem is just that I didn't use a DNS name (or IP).
So localhost in SCDF server pod is not the host and obviously nothing is running on 32000 port

Works fine with Harbor registry : [How to configure Harbor for SCDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70097345/how-to-configure-harbor-for-scdf/)