# How to configure Harbor for SCDF?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow, self-signed-certificate, harbor

I'm trying to use `Harbor` registry with `SCDF 2.9.1` in `microk8s 1.18.20`.
I successfully configure SCDF to retrieve the Docker Labels of my apps by adding this in SCDF server Config Map :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      container:
        registry-configurations:
          harbor:
            registry-host: myhost
            authorization-type: dockeroauth2
            user: myuser
            secret: mypwd
            disable-ssl-verification: true
            extra:
              "registryAuthUri" : 'https://myhost/service/token?service=harbor-registry&scope=repository:{repository}:pull'
```

Then for pulling images I created a secret with this command line (after configuring my local Docker daemon) :

```
microk8s.kubectl create secret generic harbor-credentials \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/home/myuser/.docker/config.json \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

And change Skipper and SCDF Config Map to use it with :

```
spring.cloud.skipper.server.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.imagePullSecret=harbor-credentials
spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.imagePullSecret=harbor-credentials
```

But when I try to deploy my app in a stream, I get this error when pulling the image :

```
Head "https://myhost/v2/scdf/myapp/manifests/latest": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

How and where do I have to configure Harbor self-signed certificate so that SCDF/Skipper can deploy applications ?
Also ideally I would prefer to remove `disable-ssl-verification: true` for Docker Labels too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple : I only had to copy the Harbor `ca.crt` file (downloaded from Harbor UI) in the `/ets/ssl/certs` directory.

You can also create the secret directly without configuring Docker daemon with something like :

```
microk8s.kubectl create secret docker-registry harbor-credentials \
    --docker-server=hostname \
    --docker-username='user' \
    --docker-password=pwd
```

Additionally if you want to use Harbor as a proxy for OCI images from docker.io, you can configure SCDF all at once by adding these properties during installation (after configuring Harbor proxy cache project `dockerhub-proxy` of course) :

```
global.imageRegistry = hostname/dockerhub-proxy
global.imagePullSecrets = [harbor-credentials]
```

In this case, your user should have rights to pull on every Harbor projects you need.
Then all images will be pulled from Harbor including kafka, skipper, zookeeper, etc ...

**EDIT** :
I share a more elegant way to configure Harbor credentials through K8S secret : add the secret as a volume like [this](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/helm/#volume-mounted-secretes).
The container registry is automatically configured. If you need to add options, you add it in the config map like this :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      container:
        registry-configurations:
          harbor:
            registry-host: myhost
            disable-ssl-verification: true
```

Mapping between the secret and the additional configuration is made based on the `registry-host` and the `docker-server` property in the secret if I understood it well

All of this can be made at once with the Helm chart (since v5.0.1) with a YAML like that :

```
server:
  configuration:
    containerRegistries:
      harbor:
        registry-host: hostname
        disable-ssl-verification: true
  extraVolumes:
    - name: harbor
      secret:
        secretName: harbor-credentials
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: harbor
      readOnly: true
      mountPath: /etc/secrets/harbor
global:
  imageRegistry: hostname/dockerhub-proxy
  imagePullSecrets: [harbor-credentials]
deployer:
  imagePullSecrets: [harbor-credentials]
```